# How to completely remove all the driver files associated with a USB device

Tags: windows, usb, drivers

I installed drivers for a USB device I was testing
The first time I connected the device to the computer, I had to insert the device's CD into the computer and Windows automatically detected the drivers from the CD
Now I think the drivers from the CD are not the best option for the device and want to remove them so that I can test out other driver file options
However the problem is doing `Uninstall Driver` from Device Manager does not seem to completely remove the driver files from the computer, as connecting the USB device again seems to install the drivers automatically without even requiring the CD
I am assuming that the drivers are still in the computer somewhere, along with the information  about the driver's location for this particular device, in some INF file.
How can I manually find out where the drivers are located and which inf files are associated with that particular device?
As far as possible I want to do this without installing any other software
I am using Windows XP service pack 3, but I would like to do this for Windows 7 as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try USBDeview (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html)...

Comment: This isn't an answer. The "uninstall selected devices" in USBDeview does nothing different that the builtin Windows option to do this

Comment: The question also specifies no other software. It doesn't look like you read the question at all.

Comment: "As far as possible" ;)